# How to call procedure in oracle for input parameter as types?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Code segment for oracle to call proc where we are using type variables as a input parameter.

1- By this approach we could call proc of input type parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE callbck AS TABLE OF callback_t;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CALLBACK_T AS OBJECT
(
   p_grading_id NUMBER,
   p_name VARCHAR2 (500),
   p_value VARCHAR2 (500)
);
CREATE TABLE CALLBACK_T_temp
(
   p_grading_id   NUMBER,
   p_name         VARCHAR2 (500),
   p_value        VARCHAR2 (500)
);
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_errors (p_error_message IN callbck)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO CALLBACK_T_temp
      SELECT *
        FROM TABLE (p_error_message) COMMIT;
END;
/
SELECT * FROM CALLBACK_T_temp;
COMMIT;
DECLARE
   P_ERROR_MESSAGE   callbck;
BEGIN
   P_ERROR_MESSAGE :=
      callbck (CALLBACK_T (1, 'name1', 'value1'),
               CALLBACK_T (1, 'name2', 'value2'),
               CALLBACK_T (1, 'name3', 'value3'));
   CRADLE_DEV_ENV11_O.LOG_ERRORS (P_ERROR_MESSAGE);
   COMMIT;
END;
SELECT * FROM CALLBACK_T_temp;
TRUNCATE TABLE CALLBACK_T_temp;
```

2- this is another approach by which  we could call proc of input type parameter.

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
   p_grading_id   NUMBER,
   p_name         VARCHAR2 (500),
   p_value        VARCHAR2 (500)
);
INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (1, 'name1', 'value1');
INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (1, 'name2', 'value2');
INSERT INTO temp
     VALUES (1, 'name3', 'value3');
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM temp;
DECLARE
   P_ERROR_MESSAGE   callbck;
BEGIN
   SELECT CALLBACK_T (e.p_grading_id, e.p_name, e.p_value)
     BULK COLLECT INTO P_ERROR_MESSAGE
     FROM temp e;
   CRADLE_DEV_ENV11_O.LOG_ERRORS (P_ERROR_MESSAGE);
END;
/
SELECT * FROM CALLBACK_T_temp;
TRUNCATE TABLE CALLBACK_T_temp;
```

3- By this approach we could call proc of input type parameter but object type inside object type.

```
CALLING OBJECT INSIDE OBJECT
**DECLARE
   P_VALUES   P_OBJECT;
BEGIN
   P_VALUES :=
      P_OBJECT (
         1000,
         name_value_table (name_value_object ('NAME1', 'VALUE1'),
                           name_value_object ('NAME2', 'VALUE2'),
                           name_value_object ('NAME3', 'VALUE3')));
   PKG.PROC (P_VALUES);
   COMMIT;
END**;
```

So is there any other way by which we could call procedure of input parameter as type.

Comment: Not sure I understand completely, BUT in oracle plsql it is possible to call at procedure with a custom type as parameter, but it is important that all references are declared with exactly the same TYPE. It is not enough that two types look the same. So as long as your variables, arguments, columns etc. are declared using THE SAME type it should work.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?